# Disable alt tab window switching in Gnome 2

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome2

How do I disable the alt+tab switching between Gnome 2 windows?

Which part of Gnome is responsible for doing the alt+tab ? metacity ?

I am using Gnome 2.16.0 (RHEL5). I do not see any keyboard shortcut for alt+tab, when listing the configuration database:

```
$ gconftool-2 -R / | egrep -i alt
  mouse_button_modifier = <Alt>
  switch_to_workspace_down = <Control><Alt>Down
  switch_to_workspace_left = <Control><Alt>Left
  switch_to_workspace_up = <Control><Alt>Up
  switch_to_workspace_right = <Control><Alt>Right
  move_to_workspace_up = <Shift><Control><Alt>Up
  maximize = <Alt>F10
  unmaximize = <Alt>F5
  minimize = <Alt>F9
  begin_move = <Alt>F7
  move_to_workspace_down = <Shift><Control><Alt>Down
  move_to_workspace_right = <Shift><Control><Alt>Right
  move_to_workspace_left = <Shift><Control><Alt>Left
  begin_resize = <Alt>F8
```

On the web there are some questions relating to alt+tab and Gnome 3, but nothing about completely disabling alt+tab in Gnome 3.

Background:
I am running linux in a RealVNC window on a Windows10 pc, and would like alt+tab to switch between my Windows10 windows, and not between Gnome windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gconftool-2 --type string --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/switch_windows disabled
```